# Exception Value: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

The below Django view keeps throwing the error

> Exception Value:   global name 'images' is not defined

**views.py**

```
PATH_ONE_IMAGES = ['P1D1.jpg', 'P2D2.jpg', 'P3D3.jpg', 'P4D4.jpg', 'P5D5.jpg', 'P6D6.jpg', 'P7D7.jpg', 'P8D8.jpg', 'P9D9.jpg']


class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                      
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  
        if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16']:
            print '\nThe available list of Path_One images is', PATH_ONE_IMAGES

            images = []
            step = int(self.steps.current)

            if step in (5, 6, 7):
                images[step - 5] = image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)          
                PATH_ONE_IMAGES.remove(image)
                context['display_image'] = image

            elif step == 8:
                context['first_image'] = images[0]
                context['second_image'] = images[1]
                context['third_image'] = images[2]             

            elif step in (9, 10, 11):
                images[3 + step - 9] = image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)          
                PATH_ONE_IMAGES.remove(image)
                context['display_image'] = image

            elif step == 12:
                context['fourth_image'] = images[3]
                context['fifth_image'] = images[4]
                context['sixth_image'] = images[5]

            elif step in (13, 14, 15):
                images[6 + step - 13] = image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)          
                PATH_ONE_IMAGES.remove(image)
                context['display_image'] = image

            else:# self.steps.current == '16':
                context['fourth_image'] = images[6]
                context['fifth_image'] = images[7]
                context['sixth_image'] = images[8] 

            steps = ['5','6','7','9','10','11','13','14','15']              

            context.update({'steps': steps})

        return context
```

When I define 'images' with

```
        ....
        if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16']:

            images = []
            step = int(self.steps.current)

            if step in (5, 6, 7):
        ....
```

I get

> Exception Value:   list assignment index out of range

If I add values to it

```
images = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

They become hardcoded and do not take the value of `PATH_ONE_IMAGES`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? How can I define the images array so that its list assignment index is not out of range and so it can be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted may be missing critical information, however, assuming nothing important is missing, I believe the culprit is that your code (when stripped down of useless details) looks like:

```
images = []
for x in something:
    images[index] = x
```

This is *not* valid. You cannot *add* items to a list using the normal assignment:

```
In [1]: images = []
   ...: images[0] = 1
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d32b85fdcde7> in <module>()
      1 images = []
----> 2 images[0] = 1
      3 

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

When you use the `name[index] = value` notation you can only *modify* the value at index `index` but such index *must* already exist in the list, otherwise an `IndexError` is raised.

You must either use `append` to add at the end of the list, or use `insert` to add the item in a specific index:

```
In [2]: images = []

In [3]: images.append(1)

In [4]: images
Out[4]: [1]

In [5]: images.insert(0, 2)

In [6]: images
Out[6]: [2, 1]
```

The `=` notation can change the size of a list only when using slicing:

```
In [7]: images[2:10] = range(8)

In [8]: images
Out[8]: [2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

In fact, usually operations using slicing don't raise `IndexError`. Even if `images` is an empty list you can evaluate `images[100:1000]` and it will simply evaluate to an empty list (since the indices are out of bounds it returns the empty list) while `images[100]` raises an `IndexError`).

Comment: Hi Bakuriu. I have added mode code so that you can see what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @Deepend Yes, from the code you have posted now it's clear that the problem is what I'm describing in my answer. You have `images = []` and right after that `for step in (5, 6, 7): images[step - 5] = something` which means the loop tries to do `images[0] = something` which, as I said, raises an error because `images` is empty. However I don't really get what you are trying to achieve. Your code is trying to use `images[8]` at some point, but `images` wont ever have 8 elements in that code.

Comment: I done a very bad job explaining this. Essentially the user sees a different image, selected at random, on each page. After three such pages the user is meant to see the previous three images once again. (Data Verification Page) This happens three times, or three groups of three.

Comment: I wanted to populate a list, in this case `images` with each image as they are show to the user, each image would go in in a particular position. When they were on page 5 (the first image page) the image would be saved to `images.insert(step - 5, image)` Then on step 8 i could select images[0, 1, 2] and show them to the user.

Comment: I eventually solved the issue with a lot of help, including yours here. I had never even heard of `insert` before. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use `append` function to add elements to a list

for eg

```
images=[]
images.append(5)
images.append(6)
print images
[5,6]
```

since your `step` starts from `5` implies that the `images` list starts from zero, which is correcty inserted using the append statement

so the code should be

```
f step in (5, 6, 7):
                images.append(random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES))
                PATH_ONE_IMAGES.remove(image)
                context['display_image'] = image
```